# How to manipulate the time part of a date column?

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate, posixct

How do I write this code (`hour` is from `lubridate` package)?

Objective: if hour part of PICK_DATE is later than 16:00, the ADJ_PICK_DATE should be next day 03:00. If the hour part of PICK_DATE is earlier than 03:00, then ADJ_PICK_DATE is to be same day 03:00. Problem is, when there is no change needed, the code still adds 3 hours to the PICK_DATE i.e. when the hour part of PICK_DATE is within 03:00 and 16:00.

```
x$PICK_TIME <- cut(hour(x$PICK_DATE), c(-1, 2, 15, 24), c("EARLY", "OKAY", "LATE"))    
x$ADJ_PICK_DATE <- ifelse(x$PICK_TIME=="EARLY",
                          as.POSIXct(paste(format(x$PICK_DATE, "%d-%b-%Y"), "03:00"),
                                 format="%d-%b-%Y %H:%M"), x$PICK_DATE)
x$ADJ_PICK_DATE <- ifelse(x$PICK_TIME=="LATE",
                          as.POSIXct(paste(format(x$PICK_DATE+86400, "%d-%b-%Y"),
                                           "03:00"), format="%d-%b-%Y %H:%M"),
                          x$ADJ_PICK_DATE)
x$ADJ_PICK_DATE <- as.POSIXct(x$ADJ_PICK_DATE, origin = "1970-01-01")
```

Help please.

Sample data:

```
PICK_DATE   SHIP_DATE
01-APR-2017 00:51   02-APR-2017 06:55 AM
01-APR-2017 00:51   02-APR-2017 12:11 PM
01-APR-2017 00:51   02-APR-2017 12:11 PM
01-APR-2017 00:51   02-APR-2017 09:39 AM
```

Comment: please provide [sample data](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please review [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple, reproducible example. I had to make up some sample data, based on an earlier question you asked. I suggest reading into `dplyr` and `lubridate` as they will help you with your work on manipulating dates.

EDIT: Updated to work with end-of-month dates.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(pick_date = c("01-APR-2017 00:51", "02-APR-2017 08:53", "15-APR-2017 16:12", "23-APR-2017 02:04", "30-APR-2017 20:08"), ship_date = c("05-APR-2017 06:55", "09-APR-2017 12:11", "30-APR-2017 13:11", "02-MAY-2017 15:16", "05-MAY-2017 09:57"))

df %>% 
    mutate(pick_date = dmy_hm(pick_date)) %>% 
    mutate(ship_date = dmy_hm(ship_date)) %>% 
    mutate(pick_time = case_when(
        hour(pick_date) <= 3 ~ "early",
        hour(pick_date) >= 16 ~ "late",
        TRUE ~ "okay")
    ) %>% 
    mutate(new_pick_time = case_when(
        pick_time == "early" ~ hms(hours(3)),
        pick_time == "late" ~ hms(hours(3)),
        TRUE ~ hms(paste0(hour(pick_date), "H ", minute(pick_date), "M ", second(pick_date), "S")))
    ) %>% 
    mutate(temp_pick_date = case_when(
        pick_time == "early" ~ pick_date,
        pick_time == "late" ~ pick_date + days(1),
        TRUE ~ pick_date)
    ) %>% 
    mutate(new_pick_date = make_datetime(year(temp_pick_date), month(temp_pick_date), day(temp_pick_date), hour(new_pick_time), minute(new_pick_time), second(new_pick_time))) %>%
    select(-new_pick_time, -temp_pick_date)
```

This returns

```
            pick_date           ship_date pick_time       new_pick_date
1 2017-04-01 00:51:00 2017-04-05 06:55:00     early 2017-04-01 03:00:00
2 2017-04-02 08:53:00 2017-04-09 12:11:00      okay 2017-04-02 08:53:00
3 2017-04-15 16:12:00 2017-04-30 13:11:00      late 2017-04-16 03:00:00
4 2017-04-23 02:04:00 2017-05-02 15:16:00     early 2017-04-23 03:00:00
5 2017-04-30 20:08:00 2017-05-05 09:57:00      late 2017-05-01 03:00:00
```

Comment: @Arani Many more people will be able to help you if you provide a simple, minimal, reproducible example, including sample data. This makes it easier for the community to understand your problem and help. I was only able to help because I saw your previous question and so had a bit more understanding of what you were after. In future, please make sure to provide more context and sample data.

Comment: Thank you for taking the effort. This question was actually teared from a previous one, thats why I forgot to add data. Also, I understand the need for simpler statements. Thank you again, both for the answer, which I will test now, and the advice.

Comment: I was facing a problem with month end dates giving `NA` results in the `new_pick_date` column. Using `pick_date+86400` for `pick_time=="late"` argument in the last `case_when` can solve that issue.

Comment: @Arani Glad this worked with you. I've just updated my answer to work with end-of-month dates as well. Sorry for the delay, was moving house!

Answer (score 1):

So it sounds like you just need to do two different arithmetic operations, conditional on the hour of a date time?

The simplest way I can think to access the hour component is to store the time in a `POSIXlt`.  I believe the "l" stands or "list", and this lets you treat a timestamp like a list with the different time measurements being accessible attributes accordingly.

Like this:

```
> time <- as.POSIXlt('2017-07-29 15:12:01')
> time
[1] "2017-07-29 15:12:01 EDT"
> time$hour
[1] 15
```

So you could write a function that does the operation you desire, and feed it your date column.  Hard for me to take it further because I don't quite understand the question, but here's a skeleton:

```
ComputeDifference <- function(time) {

     if (time$hour < 3) {
       # code to count orders between 0 and 3 "from same day 3:00"

    }
    if (time$hour > 16) {
      # code to consider late orders

    }

}
```

If you throw in sample data and refine the question, maybe I can take a more thorough crack at this.

Comment: This is an excellent answer given the chaos in the initial code and the lack of data. The only clarification (not because anything is wrong but because times are frustrating to work with and most people do not know the differences), make sure you use `POSIXlt` if you want to extract using time$hour, that does not work in `POSIXct`. IF you would rather use lubridate, the format is hour(time) to get to the same 15. Otherwise this is elegant and simple!